# Defining a type inside a CRTP of a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am attempting to create a CRTP class that has an undefined class inside it --- to be defined by the deriving class, as such:

```
#include <memory> // unique_ptr

template<typename T>
class crtp
{
    public:
        class inside;

        crtp();

        std::unique_ptr<inside> m;
};
```

This works for non-templated data types.

However, if I attempt to pass it a templated class, for instance:

```
template<>
template<typename T>
class crtp<test::TestClass<T>>::inside
{
    public:
        inside()
        {
            std::cout << "Instantiated." << std::endl;
        }
};
```

It gives the following error:

```
error: invalid class name in declaration of ‘class crtp<test::TestClass<T> >::inside’
```

I am using gcc 4.6.1.

What am I missing here? I feel like it has something to do with how templates are instantiated, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

EDIT: To clarify, things like crtp's constructor are already defined elsewhere (should I post it? It's just initializing the unique_ptr). The only thing that I want to have to specialize is the definition of the inside class.

Comment: Could you describe in more detail why you are using CRTP? Do you want to create a `std::unique_ptr<T>` where you can pass in `T`? I don't understand the need for the inside class.

Comment: Basically, I'm attempting to allow it to have a different inside class with a common interface that the derived classes (TestClass) in this case can access. A probably better comparison is to something like a pimpl setup, where inside contains the actual private workings of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't partially-specialize the outer template to define the nested class; only full specialization is permissible (such as `template <> class crtp<int>::inside`). Instead, you could provide a partial specialization of the entire template:

```
template <typename T>
class crtp<test::TestClass<T>>
{
public:
    class inside { /* ... */ };
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Hrm, I see. However, this would require me to copy the entirety of crtp's implementation for every partial specialization I make (eg, crtp's constructor, data members, and such), as I understand? A quick test with some code shows that, for instance, I have to recopy things like the m unique_ptr and such, otherwise the specialization has no access to it, as opposed to me being able to keep a consistent template interface for TestClass to use.

Comment: You can always factor things so that you don't have to repeat yourself. For example, you could define a `template <typename T> class next_to;` in adherent `namespace detail`, and then define `typedef detail::next_to<T> inside;` inside your class.